# Python3: regex code with carret or dollar sign doesn't match anything

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Does anyone have an idea why a regex code that works perfectly finding 
shutil.move() does not find anything if I add the carret and dollar sign at the beginning and end of the regex code?

```
exampleRegex = re.compile (r'(shutil[.])(.*)(\)\s)') --> finds all shutil functions

exampleRegex = re.compile (r'^(shutil[.])(.*)(\)\s)$') --> doesn't find anything
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also share here the string you're testing these regex against? That would help :)

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The only thing I could suggest is that you're using a string that contains more than `shutil\.`, followed by anything, followed by `) ` (where the space at the end could be any whitespace character). Are you sure your strings are exactly as you describe? Also, assuming this is a multiline file/input, do you have the multiline `m` modifier enabled? Beyond these suggestions, we cannot really provide any further assistance without having the actual input.

Comment: Have you tried using regular strings and doubling up the backslashes?

Comment: The trailing \s (matches unicode whitespace characters) may be what is tripping you up - is this really needed?  I may not be correct but from a quick read of Python's definitive regex documentation (docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) there are some unexpected implications you have to be aware of when using \s - especially with $ since the $ requires a trailing unicode whitespace character.

Comment: I find it helpful to use online regex tools when debugging regex expressions.  Here is one specifically for Python flavor regex. https://pythex.org/

Answer (score 0):

Because your string probably isn't just `shutil.move()`.

I suggest you read up on regex and how they work. Here is a decent place to start https://github.com/zeeshanu/learn-regex/blob/master/README.md.

Comment: The definiive  me differnces https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html

Comment: What I meant to say is that I believe Python reqex has it's own quirks.  You may need to refer to the definitive regex documention at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html.  A widget at the top left of that page will allow you to change to the specific version (2.x, 3.x) that you are using.